# Trying to pull emails from large docx with Python Docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

Newbie here.

I am trying to save myself hours of work manually going through a large word document to pull out all the emails.

So far I created this little script:

```
import re
from docx import Document

document = Document('directory.docx')

email_list = []

for para in document.paragraphs:
    emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', para.text)
    if emails:
        with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f: 
          for item in emails:      
             f.write("%s\n" % item)      
    else:
        print("email not found")
```

Unfortunately I am only getting "Email not found" although there are many emails in the document. The Regular expression I believe is correct.

Comment: What is the format of an email within the docx.  Can you provide a few examples?

Comment: I have now updated the question to show a working code example, but from a large docx with many emails, only one is being pulled. It makes no sense as it is the same format throughout

Answer (score 1):

You did:

```
  for para in document.paragraphs:
    emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", r"para")
```

which mean you instructed `findall` to search in `r"para"` *string*, whilst you probably mean `para` *variable*, please try changing your code to

```
  for para in document.paragraphs:
    emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", para)
```

and write what effect you get

Comment: So I fixed the issue by using `code`para.text`code` rather than para in string format. But unfortunately it seems that I am only getting one email from a very large document containing several pages